# SensorManager : magnetic field range

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am searching for hours but I cannot find an example or definition for the range of the magnetic field sensor

And ..the [links](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX) says:

```
MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MIN : 30.0 
MAGNETIC_FIELD_EARTH_MAX : 60.0
```

My sensor detecs values < 0 ... Am i on the Moon ? ;)

Thanks !

Comment: unfortunately i havent found about this ( real spec ) but i received a max value 1000, ( near a headset ) i think this is the max value

Answer (score 4):

u cant get a negative magnetic (overall) power. the negative values are showing the positions of the magnetic field according the x,y,z axis.

to calculate the total magnet power you have to use:

```
double teslaXYZ = Math.sqrt((magnetX*magnetX)+(magnetY*magnetY)+(magnetZ*magnetZ));
```

this value minimum is 0 nt and maximum is 200 nt.

the earth's minimum is 20 nt to 70 nt depends where you are on earth..

Answer (score 4):

to get the strength of the magnetic field, you have to get the x,y,z values of the magnetic field (from Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), and apply the following formula:

```
double magnetic_field_strength = Math.sqrt( (Xvalue*Xvalue) + (Yvalue*Yvalue) + (Zvalue*Zvalue) );
```

magnetic_field_strength is actually expressed in **microtesla (µT)** and not nanotesla (nT) as suggested in a previous answer
It could be noted that the average magnetic field strength of the Earth is 50 µT, according to [this website](http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~scidemos/Geophysics/EarthsMagneticField/EarthsMagneticField.html).

So a possible code would be:

```
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {   
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            magnetic_field_strength = Math.sqrt((event.values[0]*event.values[0])+(event.values[1]*event.values[1])+(event.values[2]*event.values[2]));
            break;                      
        default: 
            return;
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer here: http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator for all sensors

anyway there is no max value for the magnetic field itself so the max range has to be determined by a device. check out the docs.